# Insecure handling of signed_request

Tags: facebook, security

I've noticed several FB applications that handle signed_request in an insecure way. F.ex I load an application as from a page-tab, FB posts the signed_request to the app. The app then redirects me further into their site passing the signed_request as a get variable.

In theory it's atleast less secure, have Facebook put out any guidelines/rules on how to handle signed_requests or are applications free to do whatever they want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> F.ex I load an application as from a page-tab, FB posts the signed_request to the app. The app then redirects me further into their site passing the signed_request as a get variable.

Passing it via GET is not harmful per se – as long as you embed no external resources into your page (because those are likely to get it transfered as HTTP referer).

But I don’t see any real reason to pass the signed_request parameter around – once it is decoded and verified, I put it into my session and have access to it whenever I want.

> In theory it's atleast less secure, have Facebook put out any guidelines/rules on how to handle signed_requests or are applications free to do whatever they want?

Handling the token is your responsibility – and if you do it in a way that it gets stolen and is misused for spam, FB will most likely block your app.